# Structure pointer to function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a structure I created in a function to another function so basically what im trying to do is dynamically create the amount of structures needed the amount of structures is in a text file so in the text file there would be a number like 5 and and 5 data sets. I want to pass the structures I created in my function to another function. I started programming a few months ago so forgive me if there is a simple solution or if this question has been asked.

```
struct graph
{
int Max,Min,index;
double dataArray[300];
};

void readfile()
{
int amount;
char tmpSTR,nmbrGraph;
ifstream myFile("data1.txt",ios::in);
myFile>>amount;
myFile>>tmpSTR;
myFile>>nmbrGraph;
graph* Data = new graph[amount];

    for(int j=0;j<nmbrGraph;j++)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<299;i++)
        myFile>>Data[j].dataArray[i];
    }
//hOW WOULD I PASS THE STRUCTURE "DATA" TO THE FUNCTION anotherFunction?
}

void anotherFunction()
{
for(int i = 0;i<300;i++)
cout<<Data[scroll].dataArray[i])<<endl; /*Error here! scroll being an 
integer declared globally*/
}
```

Comment: "...pass the structures I created in my function to another function" - *parameters* will be required unless you're planning on using an ill-advised stack of global variables. Also, for your sake I hope `nmbrGraph <= amount`  in the posted code is really true, or you're already invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `graph*` pointer by value or reference to `anotherFunction` as an argument.  Also, it is important to include the number items, as that was determined by reading the file and not knowable beforehand.

```
// by value
void anotherFunction(graph* Data, int amount);
// by reference
void anotherFunction(graph*& Data, int amount);
```